# Perl convert date timezone without datetime module

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I have a date in the format:  05/26/2013 06:08:00
The timezone of above date is GMT -7

how can i change the above to GMT date and time and in format:
 26 May 2013 13:08:00 GMT

Note: I cannot install any perl module. I know that i can do this easily via DateTime but i cannot install it.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Perl? Why not use local::lib and install DateTime for you?

Comment: @MiguelPrz  This is a production machine. There are various reasons behind not installing perl modules. Thanks.

Comment: you are sure you know the fixed offset, that there isn't sometimes daylight savings time?

Comment: @ysth Actually i'm parsing a log file. And it is in GMT -7.

Comment: Wouldn't the GMT time be `26 May 2013 13:08:00 GMT` based on what you have on the first line?

Comment: @doubleDown  Yes, sorry edited it!

Comment: "There are various reasons behind not installing perl modules." All of them bad. If you're not using modules from CPAN then you're not using most of the power of Perl. I suggest you find a better sysadmin, manager or job :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) which should be included with your Perl installation.

```
use Time::Piece;

my $datetime = '05/26/2013 06:08:00';
$datetime   .= '-0700'; # attach the timezone offset

my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %z');
print $dt->strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S');
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is this efficient enough to run it for 10000 entries at a time?

Comment: It should be since it's a fast and light module. But it would be best if you tested it yourself.

Comment: It should be noted that `Time::Piece` only became core module with Perl v5.9.5.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your local time is already set to GMT-7, simply:

```
use POSIX 'mktime', 'strftime';
my $datetime = '05/26/2013 06:08:00';
my ($month,$day,$year,$hour,$min,$sec) = $datetime =~ m{^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)\z}
    or die "invalid datetime $datetime\n";
my $formatted_time = strftime '%e %B %Y %T %Z', gmtime mktime $sec,$min,$hour,$day,$month-1,$year-1900,0,0,0;
```

You may want `%d` instead of `%e` and/or `%b` instead of `%B`; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html and verify that the desired format specifiers are supported on your system.