# How can I convert a date time and time zone correctly?

Tags: perl, datetime

I have done some searching and I'm not sure how to get this converted correctly using core Perl modules. I have `2013-10-22T19:31:00Z` and want to get 10/22/2013 and the time in US Central time.

Comment: For converting date/time formats using core modules, see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037539/perl-convert-date-timezone-without-datetime-module), among others.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, there isn't sufficient information to answer his question in the answers to that question.

Comment: @ikegami There is, however, a link to the documentation for Time::Piece, which would be a good start.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I dont have Time::Piece

Comment: You might want to include what version of Perl you're running in the question, then.

Comment: `Time::Piece` is in core since version 9.5 of Perl5. That happened over *six years* ago. There is absolutely no reason to use any ancient Perl that predates this (doesn't the current RHEL even use v10.1?), and the current release is 18.1. Even if you can't use a recent perl, [you can always use CPAN](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/but-i-cant-use-cpan/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Perl modules?

That would include [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) that's been part of Perl since 5.10.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Time::Piece;

my $date = "2013-10-22T19:31:00Z";

my $time = Time::Piece->strptime ( $date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" );
$time = localtime($time); # Converts time to local time

say $time->mdy("/");
```

This prints out:

```
10/22/2013
```

That wacky `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` string represents the format of your time input. You can find it in your manage for [strftime](http://man.cx/strftime).

- `%Y`: Four digit year
- `%m`: Month from 01 - 12
- `%d`: Day from 01 - 31
- `%H`: Hour from 00 - 23
- `%M`: Minute from 00 - 59
- `%S`: Second from 00 - 59

Comment: That doesn't convert to central time

Comment: I've added a `localtime` function. This will convert the `$time` object into local time instead of GMT. If your local time is Central Time, this will work. Maybe the true answer is to use [Slaven's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19528445/368630) trick of setting the `$ENV{TZ} variable and running `tzset` too.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using just core modules (well, you need to have at least perl 5.8):

```
use strict;
use POSIX qw(tzset strftime);
use Time::Local qw(timegm);

my $iso_time = "2013-10-22T19:31:00Z";
my $formatted_time;
{
    local $ENV{TZ} = "America/Chicago";
    tzset;
    if (my($y,$m,$d,$H,$M,$S) = $iso_time =~ m{^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})Z$}) {
        $formatted_time = strftime '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', localtime timegm $S,$M,$H,$d,$m-1,$y;
    } else {
        # invalid ISO date, do something
    }
}
tzset; # restore default time zone handling

warn $formatted_time, "\n"; # output is "10/22/2013 14:31:00"
```

A word about the `TZ` trick: by setting the environment variable `TZ` some time-related libc functions (e.g. `localtime`) use that time zone instead of the default time zone. If the `TZ` environment variable is set within a program, then `tzset()` has to be called to adjust the internal time-related data structures. And don't forget to call `tzset()` again to restore the data structures again.

This should work on most Unix system, but may or may not work on a Windows system.

Answer (score 3):

```
use DateTime::Format::RFC3339  qw( );
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $in_dt_format = DateTime::Format::RFC3339->new();

my $out_dt_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern  => '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
    on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $in_dt_format->parse_datetime('2013-10-22T19:31:00Z');
$dt->set_time_zone('America/Chicago');
say $out_dt_format->format_datetime($dt);  # 10/22/2013 14:31:00
```

Comment: I dont have that first module `Can't locate DateTime/Format/RFC3339.pm`

Comment: @BluGeni, So install it.

Comment: not an option for me unfortunately. This is why I said I need something with just core perl modules

Comment: @BluGeni if the code you write can somehow make it onto the machine where it needs to be run, then so can the code that your code requires.

Comment: @BlueGeni, Why can you use the code I post to SO but not the code I posted to CPAN? Nonsense. Are you under the mistaken impression that special permissions are needed to install modules?